# How would a jungle dwelling humanoid canine pack oriented society be like?

Tags: society, science-fiction, aliens

If a race of pack-oriented caninoids (humanoid canines) evolved in a jungle setting, how would their society develop?

You can use real world examples in your answers.

By pack oriented, the pack could be organized like a tribe or clan.

Not sure if this makes the question board or helps it, but I'm looking to see the development from Stone Age to possibly Iron Age.

Here are some additional facts:

1: Matriarchy (although males have equal rights as males, just that females have a lot more say in the society since they are a bit stronger than males, although males are much more agile than females)

2: They would have high praise for hunters and warriors.

3: Given the fact that real life canines (both male and female) are very protective of their young, both genders would have very strong maternal instincts.

4: The jungle is rich in life (both plant and animal, so a lot of good game and food sources, but also a lot of danger too).

Comment: in my opinion they probably still similar like most human jungle tribe or hierarchy, either matriarchy or patriarchy is your own chosen, what technology they have btw? are they hunter gatherer or know farm or domestication? though regarding physic they probably has short fur just like most tropical/jungle dog here and no fur shedding as far as i know.

Answer (score 2):

They would develop as humans, probably with canine companions.

As has been noted, human group interactions are much closer to dogs than to other primates, and we appear appear to have co-evolved with dogs, taking on much of their pack structure. In a real sense, they may have domesticated us as much as we did them.